Python under Wine does not handle signals
I'm playing with python under wine. The problem I'm facing is I'm unable to catch terminate signal in the program.
I run
$ wine python -c "import signal, time; signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, print); time.sleep(60)"

Then I send SIGTERM to wine from another terminal, the program is terminated, but the signal handler is not called.
When I run the same program, but without wine, then it calls the signal handler as expected.
$ python -c "import signal, time; signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, print); time.sleep(60)"
15 <frame at 0x76d2aed86560, file '<string>', line 1, code <module>>
15 <frame at 0x76d2aed86560, file '<string>', line 1, code <module>>

What's the issue with python under wine? How to catch the termination signal, do some cleanup and then exit gracefully?
Wine: wine-9.0
Python: 3.12.5

SIGTERM is a Unix-concept and does not exist in Windows. Windows does not have a single catch-all equivalent to SIGTERM, rather the method to ask a program to cleanly shutdown varies depending on situation.
The messaging system typically used for GUI applications is quite different from Unix signals, but for console applications, Windows does have Console Control Handlers, which includes events like CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT and CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, which tell a console application that it needs to close because the terminal it is attached to is closing or the user running it is logging off. These cannot be easily sent to another process in Windows, but this system does also have CTRL_C_EVENT, which would be akin to the Unix SIGINT and is delivered to a console application when the user presses CTRL+C. In my own experience WINE will translate a SIGINT to a CTRL_C_EVENT, and it appears that in Windows, Python does register handling Windows' CTRL_C_EVENT with signal.SIGINT.
I'm not sure of your ultimate goal with running Python under WINE, but for the example you provided, I believe replacing signal.SIGTERM with signal.SIGINT and sending SIGINT to the process would likely be the easiest alternative to run the signal handler.
